# Pass data back to uiviewcontroller on pop (NavigationController.PopViewController)

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iOS application using Xamarin.iOS (Code only, no storyboards) and I wonder what the best way to send data back to the original uiviewcontroller when I pop from the navigationcontroller.

In android I use StartActivityForResult and then override OnResult, but I can't find a similar way for iOS.

I know there's overrides for ViewDidLoad, ViewDidAppear, etc, what I'm looking for is some kind of ViewDidGetPoppedBackTo (hope you get it).

Or is there another better way to achieve this?

Comment: Custom methods on your UIViewControllers, global variables, NSNotificationCenter, CoreData triggers/notifications, custom Delegates, Key/Value observers, C# event handlers, etc... Assuming you are not using any "framework" like Viper or MVVM :-( the iOS/macOS centric way would be to implement a custom delegate on your view controller and call the delegate's methods (if available) during the `popViewControllerAnimated`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigationController` keeps track of all the ViewControllers as an array:  `NavigationController.ViewControllers`

You can get an existing instance of the `ViewController` Type from this array via following code:
(You may write this method in `BaseViewController` if you have it.)

```
public T InstanceFromNavigationStack<T> () where T : UIViewController
{
    return (T)NavigationController.ViewControllers.FirstOrDefault(v => v is T);
}
```

Then use it like :

```
var myVCInstance = InstanceFromNavigationStack<MyTargetViewController>();
if(myVCInstance != null)
{
    //Assign a value like
    myVCInstance.MyVariable = "MyValue";

    //Or call a method like
    myVCInstance.MethodToReloadView("MyValue")
}
//Go Back Navigation Code
//Then here write your navigation logic to go back.
```

This not only helps passing data in Previous ViewController, but Any ViewController in the stack. Simply pass the Type of it to get an Instance from Stack.

**NOTE:** This should work if your Navigation stack doesn't have multiple instance of the same `ViewController` Type.

Comment: Right click on FirstOrDefault() method and resolve the missing namespace  System.Linq;

Comment: I found out that this doesn't work if an item in the stack is a UITabBarController, do you know why? 

OrderInfoTabController myInstance = Utils.InstanceFromNavigationStack<OrderInfoTabController>(source);
^ myInstance becomes null

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
ViewController viewController = (ViewController)NavigationController.TopViewController;
viewController.SendData(myevent);
```

Create method `SendData` in your `ToViewController` this method is called first when navigationg back and your data send to your previous ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I've started using is `EventHandler` methods. Here is an example I use to populate a `UITextField` in the parent view controller with the selection from a `UITableView` (child view controller) and then close the child.

Define the `EventHandler` method in your parent view controller:

```
void LocationLookup_OnSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chosenLocation = (MKPlacemark)sender;
    planLocation.Text = chosenLocation.Name;

    this.ParentViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
}
```

Pass the `EventHandler` method from the parent as a property of the child.

```
public partial class LocationLookupViewController : UITableViewController
{
    private event EventHandler OnSelected;

    public LocationLookupViewController(EventHandler OnSelected)
    {
        this.OnSelected = OnSelected;
    }

    ...
}
```

Call the `EventHandler` passing in the object / data that you need in the parent

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    ...

    OnSelected(response?.MapItems[0].Placemark, new EventArgs());   
}
```

*Note* - The above class and function are incomplete but should provide you with an idea of how this technique works.